# Aligning text in unordered lists vertically does not work

Tags: html, css

This is the problem I'm having:[image: I have a problem like this] (bottom text not aligning vertically)

This is a simple unordered list with a link tag. I am using a CSS stylesheet. I understand to fix this issue I need to add this definition into this stylesheet:

```css
ul {
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Test 1</li>
<li>Test 2</li>
</ul>
```

This does not seem to fix my problem, although other style settings applied here does work. Does anyone know why? Thank you!

Comment: can you add more code.

Comment: Typo in the selector: `u1` should be `ul`.

Comment: @myf - Thanks I did not realise this! But somehow creating an unordered list works with <u1 and not with <ul> for me. I then switched to a different document and both works. This is really strange.

Comment: That's most probably because `<li>` elements are styled that way even outside `<ul>` context, what is semantically invalid. It's the nature of HTML and CSS that it's resilient and tolerates even this kind of structure.
If you inspect given element in your browser's Developer Tools (with UA styles enabled) you should find the origins of its appearance.

Comment: You are right, I inspected element and it is shown as `<ul>`. I also tried deleting my referenced css stylesheet and <ul> worked perfectly fine. What I don't understand is why I'm unable to create <ul> with my stylesheet referenced.